# Regex match last occurance before

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

i'd expact `\d{3}(?=.*(?!\d{3})string)` to match only the *333* here
`000 111 222 333 string 444 555 666` - but it did not.
Anyone an idea why?

---

i'd also expect that in this case `000 111 222 333 sdfasdjf;sdfjn 999 skljdfn\;sdlfn\sd string 444 555  666` only 999 got a match .. just to clearify.

i tried nested positive and negativ lookahead and lookbehind in many constellations and to accomplish that and became a bit curious and a bit desperated.. not longer sure that regex can do that.. so please if you have any suggestion (else than use a different tool) - lmk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\d{3}(?=.*(?!\d{3})string)` pattern matches any 3 digits that are followed with any 0+ chars as many as possible and then a `string` text that does not start with 3 digits - which is always true, `string` does not start with 3 digits.

You may use

```
\d{3}(?!.*\d{3}.*string)(?=.*string)
```

Or, if the 3-digit chunks must be matched as whole words:

```
\b\d{3}\b(?!.*\b\d{3}\b.*string)(?=.*string)
```

Or - if these 3 digits must always be enclosed with whitespaces

```
(?<!\S)\d{3}(?!\S)(?!.*(?<!\S)\d{3}(?!\S).*string)(?=.*string)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GU6O3Y/1)

Here, after matching three digits,

- `(?!.*\d{3}.*string)` - negative lookahead makes sure there are no 3 digits and then `string` anwhere to the right of the current location
- `(?=.*string)` - a positive lookahead that requires `string` to appear anywhere to the right of the current location.